# Facebook login with PHP SDK , getUser() returns 0 in the callback

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have a testing Facebook login page `example.com/login-fb` it should handle the basic Facebook user is logged in, is not logged in and print info when available.
Login link generates fine, if I click it, it goes fine to facebook and returns to this same script with a $_GET parameeter - I get something like this

`example.com/login-fb/?code=AQDgxX7dkmddbaWZbTCfLf063g0aNRuHJG71pTuCmsdXTlQX9JYe1wmPl94KcFG2BkPFjgkAZ8k0_gFcECUINJ59qbOVH9J5AKHVZP5mxQ7K25qPNQW2VHEbe80uhbrHD0QB9QeP8WSr8EdnM3ocadEVqrgXAXTRu2_Q8jBYZpBZp7MrZyg9K9BhCJEiC0xnp9a-mwyMoYtpZKxhjtEAiDwJvcZgUjftRKK-0091aECRozV5gdOSdPrqKBZhsmn5sHsjbOx1zB4z8gj2LGTxQzdaRez3Jxknn6A8wpZp70jilycIdfCBA8c_b35XOg93FTM&state=8e633d68644595d174ad01d0b7aed365#_=_`

However $facebook->getUser(); is always 0 thus it still shows the LOGIN link instead of logout link and user info. any help ?

**THE CODE:** (using Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3))

```
  <?php
  //Already REQUIRED: FB-SDK, MyFacebook class, home_url() and the_print_r()

  $facebook = new MyFacebook();
  $fb_params = array(
    'scope' => 'email',
    'redirect_uri' => home_url().'/login-fb'
  );

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($fb_params);
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  $user = $facebook->getUser();

  ?>

  <?php the_print_r($user); ?>

  <?php if ($user) {  ?>
      Your user profile is
      <?php $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); ?>
      <?php print htmlspecialchars(print_r($user_profile, true)) ?>
      LOGOUT:<br><a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>"><?php echo $logoutUrl; ?></a>
  <?php } else {  ?>
      LOGIN:<br><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><?php echo $loginUrl; ?></a>
  <?php } ?>
```

## SOLVED:

Finally I wondered why is the origanl Facebook SDK's example working - and I found out - MY CODE WAS FINE ! - it was just the url handling problem - login-fb/?code was misinterpreted thus there was no $_GET['code']! - simply just call the script with extension - login-fb.php - and the problem is solved ! ...

Comment: anyone? I am willing to provide more info inf neccessary :) !

Comment: looks quite correct to me...Have you tried with a simple curl instead? It may be the function getUser(). I  forget how's that function in the PHP SDK library. You can print the access token after you get the code, or it doesn't go that far?

Comment: it was a silly url rewrite mistake :x

Comment: thanks for the upvote bro lol. Anyhow glad you solved it. It was a loop :)

Comment: I dont follow your last comment - "the upvote" and "the loop" O.o

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and scratch my head for a day. Finally this issue was resolved by updating the lib/facebook directory with the current sdk v 3.2.3 at the time I write this post.